# TextView Not Accessible

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android.I am making a random generator program which on button click generates a number and display it on textview. I am unable to access textview when i type `R.id.` i don't get the name of the textview but i get the name of the other components. My layout code is:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

  <TextView android:id="@+id/txt02" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java code is:-

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        EditText editmessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editmessage.getText().toString();
        Random r=new Random();
        int i1=(r.nextInt(80) +65);
        message += "\n " + i1;


        // Create the text view

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.); // not able to access R.id.txt02        

    }
```

Comment: Try Project->Clean.

Comment: Have you set the option build automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem most likely is that your R.java file hasn't been updated with the EditText you have added. In eclipse, you can force an update to do this. Try `Project->Clean` as mentioned by Michal Z. in the comments.

You can also set the option to build automatically in eclipse by checking the `Project->Build Automatically` option. This will ensure that eclipse will automatically build your project and update your R.java file every time you save your project.

Answer (score 0):

If cleaning your project doesn't help, I'd check your source files to make sure there isn't a line saying "import android.R" in your imports because that will import the standard Android R object (which doesn't include any of your declared resources).  Eclipse does this sometimes when you cut and paste code and it can be frustrating, but deleting the import and cleaning / building your project should fix it.